# powershell : "openssl x509 -in file.pem -text" equivalent

Tags: powershell, openssl, certificate, pem, der

I must be using the wrong query because I cannot find how to do in Powershell what I do with a simple:

```
openssl x509 -in file.pem -text
```

I guess Powershell provides native commands to show certificate details but I'm struggling in finding how.

Comment: I've found a few commands in the PKI module but nothing that looks very promising for certificate files, only for installed certificates with Get-PfxCertificate from the PKI module maybe ? Check out certutil.exe too, it's not pure powershell but it's there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`[X509Certificate]::CreateFromCertFile()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromcertfile) reads Base64 encoded DER cert files natively and works in both Windows PowerShell and newer versions:

```
$certFile = Get-Item path\to\file.pem

$xCert2Type = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]
$Certificate = $xCert2Type::CreateFromCertFile($certFile.FullName) -as $xCert2Type
```

The explicit conversion to `[X509Certificate2]` is deliberate - it exposes more metadata via properties and results in nicer default output formatting in PowerShell

Comment: `[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2] [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::CreateFromCertFile("somePath") | Select-Object *` here is oneliner